# Auto resize tinymce when key is long pressed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-4

Running into an issue where tinymce is not auto resizing when some character key is pressed continuously. Though on leaving the key the height adjusts.

Is there any way to auto resize tinymce on key down event.
I am using angularjs ui-tinymce.

Answer (score 1):

The ui-tinymce project didn't provide any service to handle manual resizing. 
Assumong there was one (named $tinyInstance) , you could do that :

Yes, you can do something like that :

```
<textarea 
  data-ui-tinymce 
  data-ng-keypress="resizeTmce()"
  data-ng-model="tinymce"
 >
</textarea>
```

and

```
function yourCTRL($scope,$tinyInstance){
  $scope.resizeTmce = $tinyInstance.resize;
}
```

But it is not the case.

So you have two solution.
A dirty solution :

```
<textarea 
  id = "tinymce"
  data-ui-tinymce 
  data-ng-keypress="resizeTmce()"
  data-ng-model="tinymce"
 >
</textarea>
```

and

```
function yourCTRL($scope){
  $scope.resizeTmce = function(){
     $('#tinymce').resize() ...
  } ;
}
```

The second, the right way to follow Angular code design is to create a directive to handle this job.

Instead of using jQuery to resize the DOM element, take a look at [the tinymce API about resizable](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:mixin.tinymce.ui.Resizable)

The aim will be your template look at this :

```
<textarea 
  data-ui-tinymce 
  data-ui-tiny-resize-onkeypress
  data-ng-model="tinymce"
 >
</textarea>
```

Or, third solution, fork the github repository and submit a PR to auto resize on key press instead of on key leave, if you think you can.
If not, [feel free to post an issue on the project](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/issues)

Comment: did you write a `$scope.resizeTmce` function in your controller ? Is your controller declared on a DOM element containing the tinymce form ?

Comment: I am using directive and added it to link function.

Comment: So, why are you using `ng-keypress` ? Please post your code template, controller and directive working together

Comment: tried it, but nothing was working. I was able to solve by overriding on keydown  event of the editor and adjusting height of iframe based on body of tinymce.